# React hook reference is lost when its called outside of React components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, notistack

The following code used to work in earlier versions of ReactJS but now it seems `useSnackbarRef` loses its value and is undefined inside `handler` function, what has changed in React and how can I fix this utility?
The goal of the utility is to enable me to call `enqueueSnackbar` from outside of react components.

```
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

let useSnackbarRef;
export const SnackbarUtilsConfigurator = () => {
    useSnackbarRef = useSnackbar();
    return null;
};

const handler = {
    success(msg) {
        this.toast(msg, { variant: 'success' });
    },
    warning(msg) {
        this.toast(msg, { variant: 'warning' });
    },
    info(msg) {
        this.toast(msg, { variant: 'info' });
    },
    error(msg) {
        this.toast(msg, { variant: 'error' });
    },
    toast(msg, { variant = 'default', ...restProps }) {
        useSnackbarRef.enqueueSnackbar(msg, { variant, autoHideDuration: 2000, ...restProps });
    },
};

export default handler;
```

Please note I also render `SnackbarUtilsConfigurator` inside my `app.js` like this:

```
<SnackbarUtilsConfigurator />
```

Comment: You cannot call hook from outside react component.

Comment: @kennarddh It was possible in previous reacts, I also render SnackbarUtilsConfigurator  inside my reactjs, infact this code is copied from here: https://dev.to/sakiblite/how-to-use-notistack-snackbar-outside-of-react-components-3ln1

Comment: What react version your previous and current?

Comment: @kennarddh My previous version was 16.8 and the current is 18.2.

Comment: I found the issue, it was a problem with my Context Providers priority, the code still works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call hook outside a react component

You can wrap `useSnackbar` as new hook

```js
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'

const useToast = () => {
  const SnackBar = useSnackbar();

  const Toast = useCallback((message, snackProps) => SnackBar.enqueueSnackbar(message, {
    autoHideDuration: 2000,
    ...snackProps
  })), [SnackBar])

  const Success = useCallback((message) => Toast(message, {
    variant: 'success'
  }), [Toast])

  const Warning = useCallback((message) => Toast(message, {
    variant: 'warning'
  }), [Toast])

  const Info = useCallback((message) => Toast(message, {
    variant: 'info'
  }), [Toast])

  const Error = useCallback((message) => Toast(message, {
    variant: 'error'
  }), [Toast])

  return {
    Toast,
    Success,
    Warning,
    Info,
    Error,
  }
}
```

You can use it like this

```js
const OtherComponent = () => {
  const { Success } = useToast()

  // You can call it here Success("message")
}
```